# Issue with passing the data from one vc to another using protocol

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols

I am trying to pass the data from UserProfileVc to ChallengeVC. I declared the protocol

```
protocol DidTapToChallengeDelegate {
    func didTapChallenge(challenge: Challenge)
}
```

```
class UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var delegate: DidTapToChallengeDelegate? 
}
```

Inside the UserProfileVc, I want to pass the data when didSelect function happens.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didTapChallenge(challenge: challenges[indexPath.row])
        let challengeVC = ChallengeVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        navigationController?.pushViewController(challengeVC, animated: true)
        }
```

Here is the code from ChallengeVC

```
class ChallengeVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, DidTapToChallengeDelegate  {
    func didTapChallenge(challenge: Challenge) {
        print("Hello, world!")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        var vc = UserProfileVC()
        vc.delegate = self
    }
```

**But however, the print statement from above does not execute when I switch to ChallengeVC.** Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't Need delegates for forward communication

```
class ChallengeVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, DidTapToChallengeDelegate  {
   var challenge: Challenge!
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // delegate?.didTapChallenge(challenge: challenges[indexPath.row])
        let challengeVC = ChallengeVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        challengeVC.challenge = challenges[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(challengeVC, animated: true)
        }
```